# Multiple UIViewControllers inside RootViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have one UIViewController which is the RootViewController inside exists a UIView which contains another UIViewController as structure is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It could be correct if your RootviewController acts like a container view controller.

check this doc on how to build that:

[Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard for your application and want to include several view controllers inside rootview controller better go for container controller which is there in Xcode itself.

If used container as a UIview controller for showing maps inside a view controller and other information related to that map was shown in the parent view controller i found it very useful and its reusable.

You can check out the below link for further information

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html